# cannot find out how to add coupons to paypal website pro checkout process

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

I've read and tested how to integrate paypal website pro to my current website for the past 2 days.

I am using paypal's latest SDK which can be downloaded: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

So far I've managed to add shipping/CC details, item details, tax details and everything else. only problem I have is how to add coupons. I've looked everywhere for a way to do that and I can't find it.

I am trying to integrate both Direct Payment. And express check-out - for now i am working on direct payment

Here is the code I got so far most of it are located in their example files.

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

$address = new AddressType();
$address->Name = "$firstName $lastName";
$address->Street1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address->Street2 = $_POST['address2'];
$address->CityName = $_POST['city'];
$address->StateOrProvince = $_POST['state'];
$address->PostalCode = $_POST['zip'];
$address->Country = $_POST['country'];
$address->Phone = $_POST['phone'];

$shippingTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 25);
$handlingTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 0);
$insuranceTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 0);

$paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
$itemTotalValue = 0;
$taxTotalValue = 0;

$itemTotalValue += 15 * 2; 
$taxTotalValue += 0 * 2;
$itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
$itemDetails->Name = 'First Item';
$itemDetails->Amount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 15);
$itemDetails->Quantity = 2;
$itemDetails->ItemCategory = 'Digital';
$itemDetails->Tax = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 0);  

$paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[0] = $itemDetails;  
//}

$orderTotalValue = $shippingTotal->value + $handlingTotal->value +
$insuranceTotal->value +
$itemTotalValue + $taxTotalValue;

$paymentDetails->ShipToAddress = $address;
$paymentDetails->ItemTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $itemTotalValue);
$paymentDetails->OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $orderTotalValue);
$paymentDetails->TaxTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $taxTotalValue);
$paymentDetails->PaymentAction = $_REQUEST['paymentType'];

$paymentDetails->HandlingTotal = $handlingTotal;
$paymentDetails->InsuranceTotal = $insuranceTotal;
$paymentDetails->ShippingTotal = $shippingTotal;

if(isset($_REQUEST['notifyURL']))
{
$paymentDetails->NotifyURL = $_REQUEST['notifyURL'];
}
```

I've dug though their classes and found a class name: `OfferCouponInfoType`

which seems to do what I am trying to achieve however I don't know how to use it.